# Deserialize JSON by passing class as string parameter

Tags: c#, json, parameter-passing, deserialization

Suppose I have this code:

```
public MessageClass(string _paramJson)
{
    string[] Messages = new string[] { "MessageA", "MessageB" };

    Messages[0] _model0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Messages[0]>(paramJson);
    Messages[1] _model1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Messages[1]>(paramJson);
}
```

I know the above won't work, but All I want is to Deserialize the JSON based on a Type passed as string parameter. ie. `MessageA`, or `MessageB`.

Even if I define `Messages` as `List<Type>` and then do `Messages.Add(typeof(MessageA));` for instance, how do I get the `type` later and passed it on to `DeserializedObject<here-some-type-from-my-list>(paramJson)` ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve that requires you to do this?

Comment: getting a json as body of HttpRequest, then need to Deserialize dynamically into one of multiple possible Message classes .. that's why

Comment: You should use a JsonConverter for that, assuming that all classes inherit from a common Message base.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you'd have to use *reflection* to convert `MessageA` and `MessageB` to a `Type` object, then use reflection to dynamically create an instance of the generic method for that type so you can invoke it.

For the first part, see the [`Type.GetType` method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var type = Type.GetType("Namespace.Prefix.Message1, AssemblyName");
```

You can skip that second part by using the [non-generic version of `DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm):

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(paramJson, type);
```

Comment: thank you Jacob .. you're so kind. I will try this and tell you my outcome.